# Measuring the amount of total influence between variables?

Tags: modeling, conditional-probability, independence, distance-functions, dependent-variable

I have a group of people with a series of yes/no questuins about preferences in various topics. The thing is they could see each other answers and change theirs hence might be influenced by a common answer. I know that non of them knew each other beforehand so I can asuuse no one is particularly biased by a spesifuc different instance

To out it more formally I have a random sample which I know the different sample points might not independent from each other. I want to measure or at least talk about the amount by which each point is influenced by **all** the rest. More formally - how each marginal distribution changes (say, in KL-divergence or Total-Variance distance) if we reveal/condition upon all the rest of the sample. It there some kind of notion to this type of dependency? Or is there anything close which I can relate to this quantity?

Comment: Can you tell us the context in which this arises? That **is**important! For instance, if your one sample is (modeled as being) exchangeable, independence cannot be discriminated empirically from exchangeable dependence!

Comment: The context is quite a toy example with synthetic data (generated for some sort of theoretical purpose).

Comment: What kind of condition it must provide in order to make it possible even approximately?

Comment: Even if it is a toy example, it must come from some real example. What is the real example you have in mind?

Comment: I have a group of people with a series of yes/no questuins about preferences in various topics. The thing is  they could see each other answers and change theirs hence might be influenced by a common answer. I know that non of them knew  each other beforehand so I can asuuse no one is particularly biased by a spesifuc different instance.

Comment: Can you please add that explanantion to the post as an edit? Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: *Influence* spreads like an evolutionary diffusion process over time. One way to model that would be to use a longitudinal network analysis. By googling 'longitudinal network analysis', many articles and papers -- mostly sociological -- will be returned.

Comment: Thanks! My case is only one time thing and not a process but I'll sure Google it.

Comment: The events recorded may have been made at a single time point but, even within that single time point, you have described a *sequence* of influence. That sequence forms a time series within a single period or window of time.